# ¿Se considerá una mal base de datos sí es de forma "ciclica"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, backend

Tengo una base de datos que se considera, para mi, "ciclico":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Independientemente de otros errores que haya dentro de este diseño (que sé que lo hay). Quiero saber especificamente de este caso...Es mala practica formar mediantes distintas relaciones un "ciclo" con ella?. Solo me gustaría saber esto

#Actualizado

Esta es la otra base de datos, sé que no es la misma con la que puse en la primera pregunta, pero tiene el mismo problema y algunos cambios similares; se elimina la relación directa entre "maestros" y "calificacion_competencia" obligandome a realizar una consulta más larga para saber que profesor puso dicha calificaión y para que estudiante

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Está es la consulta sql que hice para saber las notas asiganda por dicho maestro

```
SELECT usuarios.numero_documento, usuarios.primer_nombre, usuarios.primer_apellido,materias.nombre,competencias.competencia,calificacion_competencias.calificacion 
FROM usuarios INNER JOIN usuario_materia ON usuario_materia.fk_numero_documento = usuarios.numero_documento INNER JOIN materias ON materias.id_materias = usuario_materia.fk_id_materia 
INNER JOIN materia_competencia ON materia_competencia.fk_id_materias = materias.id_materias 
INNER JOIN  competencias ON materia_competencia.fk_id_competencia = competencias.id_competencias 
INNER JOIN calificacion_competencias ON calificacion_competencias.fk_id_competencias = competencias.id_competencias 
WHERE usuarios.numero_documento = "41056907"
```

Y este es el resultado de la consulta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien, aquí va el problema...No importa que otro numero de documento coloque en el "WHERE", me aparecerá las mismas notas:

Consulta SQL donde se cambia el numero de documento del maestro anterior por otro maestro cualquiera:

```
SELECT usuarios.numero_documento, usuarios.primer_nombre, usuarios.primer_apellido,materias.nombre,competencias.competencia,calificacion_competencias.calificacion 
FROM usuarios 
INNER JOIN usuario_materia ON usuario_materia.fk_numero_documento = usuarios.numero_documento 
INNER JOIN materias ON materias.id_materias = usuario_materia.fk_id_materia 
INNER JOIN materia_competencia ON materia_competencia.fk_id_materias = materias.id_materias 
INNER JOIN  competencias ON materia_competencia.fk_id_competencia = competencias.id_competencias 
INNER JOIN calificacion_competencias ON calificacion_competencias.fk_id_competencias = competencias.id_competencias 
WHERE usuarios.numero_documento = "12345678"
```

El resultado es este, me trae los mismos resultados (excepto que no trae calificaciones de la materia de lenguaje ya que este maestro no ha puesto calificaciones en esa materia):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me trae las calificaciones del otro maestro...Por eso me vi en la necesidad de crear una relación mas directa entre maestro y calificaciones_competencias. Por si es necesario, colocaré los datos que poseen algunas tablas:

*calificacio_competencias:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*competencias:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*materia_competencia:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*materias:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*usuario_materia:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esta pregunta, sin todo el contexto de la otra, tambien es mala... en realidad, la respuesta es depende... no sabemos que son esas tablas, como para saber si la relacion ciclica esta bien o mal... los nombres, no dicen nada, son nombres...

Comment: vamos a hacer asi.. explicame porque hay una relacion entre maestros y calificacion competencia... cuando ya sabes que maestro hizo esa calificacion....

Comment: Es una [mala práctica](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3347008/1545868) la redundancia relacional en un modelo de base de datos. Además de que es altamente susceptible a la pérdida de integridad en las operaciones en cascada.

Comment: Yo te recomendaría olvidarte de las "malas practicas", tu debes pensar en un modelo que satisfaga las necesidades de tu proyecto. Luego cuando avanzas y vas construyendo te puedes dar cuenta que falta o sobra algo, pues lo cambias y ya. No puedes pretender anticipar todos los problemas cuando estas modelando.

Comment: En teoría, la redundancia debe evitarse (porque debes sincronizar 2+ tablas), pero esa relación circular que tu tienes no significar que exista esa redundancia. Imagina que tu quieres guardar la estructura de un árbol, un caso típico es un foro donde un `Post` está relacionado con un `Post padre` , es decir tienes una relación "cíclica" en una sola tabla y no tiene nada malo. porque `Post` y `Post Padre` son distintos.

Comment: En tu caso, tu modelo puede responder a que un profesor dicta el curso y otro (o el mismo) es quien evalúa una competencia, ya sea porque así es el sistema en el colegio o porque el profesor se enfermó.  Entonces, que una línea de relaciones empiece y termine en una misma tabla, provocando eso que tu llamas "cíclicos" no quiere decir redundancia de datos, y en otros caso la redundancia debe existir, porque existen casos de borde que se deben considerar como que un profesor se enfermó y tu requieres dejar constancia de quien ha evaluado dicho contenido

Comment: @gbianchi es que es demasiada información y no sé muy bien como explicarselo para que la pregunta se considere correcta. Pero respondiendo a tu pregunta entre la relación de maestro y calificación competencias esta se debe a que un maestro debe asignar las notas de cada competencias, son ellos los encargado de dar las notas de cada competencias para cada estudiante

Comment: y?? entonces porque vas por los dos lados??? si la calificacion la da el maestro, que es quien da el curso, para que necesitas una relacion de maestro con calificacion competencia????

Comment: @aeportugal gracias por responder y es precisamente que quiero evitar cosas así. No tengo muy bien en claro el tema de "redundancia relacional", pero me imagino que debe ser datos duplicados. en diferentes partes de la DB

Comment: @gbianchi para especificar quien ha puesto esa calificación,no?. Porqué ya lo he intentado hacer la consulta por el otro lado, pero por más que filtre con un WHERE por el numero de documento del maestro, me trae todas las notas de las competencias que ha puesto todos los maestros

Comment: si tu problema son las consultas, debemos revisar tus consultas... no modificar el modelo para simplificar tus consultas... ahi esta tu problema... la calificacion la pone otro maestro que nada que ver con el que da la clasE???

Comment: @gbianchi algo así...  Verás, yo al hacer la consulta por el lado mas largo (es decir, por el lado de maestros,cursos,materias,ect..) me arroja todas las calificaciones de toda la tabla, pero con el nombre del maestro que filtre. Algo así:
... WHERE usuario.numero_documento = '11111111' AND roles.nombre = 'maestro' (procedo a ejecutar la consulta)
Después de esto lo que me arroja es el nombre del maestro, pero seguido de todas las notas  que está en la tabla (cosa que no está bien, no todas las notas lo puse él)

Comment: perdon no, pero ahi parecen fallar mil otras cosas que no estas mostrando, como los joins y otras condiciones... si tenes el numero de documento, el rol es redundante (el documento ya tiene un rol) y entonces, ya todo me hace dudar, que tu problema no es tu modelo, si no tus consultas, y ajustaste un modelo que puede ser muchisimo mas simple a tus problemas para hacer las consutlas... si es asi, todo tu modelo esta incorrecto

Comment: Compartiré la consulta SQL una vez lo haya hecho

Comment: @gbianchi entiendo. Ya mismo haré la consulta para mostratela, pero la haré en el segundo modelo que hice (donde se elimina la relación de maestro y calificaión_competencia y que me obliga si o si a recorrer el camino mas largo).

Comment: Todo muy lindo... pero es imposible probar eso con imagenes ;)... hace un fiddle en algun lado con esa informacion... mientras tanto, voy a mirar tus querys...

Comment: lo que esta haciendo, esta perfecto para los datos que tenes.. tu problema, esta en tus datos, como cargaste los datos, y como modelaste las tablas.. si los dos profesores dieron la misma materia, y vos no armaste una tabla intermedia que los una, entonces tus querys van a devolver cualquier cosa... yo te recomendaria, que te sientes con tu profesor, y empieces de vuelta a ver tus modelos. No estan mal, son incoherentes a lo que queres hacer, y les falta modelizacion de base de datos...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147956/discussion-between-gbianchi-and-mattteuz).